# Unable to change y-axis value dynamically based on data for Stacked bar chart in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

My Objective to show the y-axis value dynamically in the chart. If my data contains below 100 i.e(highest value in data = 75) then it should show 80 as highest number in y-axis. it should not show 500 in the y-axis.

```
<Bar
    data={this.state.data}
    width={400}
    height='150'
    options={{
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'point',
            intersect: false,
        },

        responsive: true,
        scales: {
        xAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
            }],
            yAxes: [{
  stacked: false,
  ticks: {
    beginAtZero: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500
  }
}, {
  id: "bar-stacked",
  stacked: true,
  display: false,
  ticks: {
    beginAtZero: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500
  },
  type: 'linear'
}]
        }
    }}
/>
```

Is it possible to make it dynamic? If yes, Can anyone help me in this query?

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46053779/2358409

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically compute the ticks you need a couple things.

1. A utility to precompute and find the maximum value in your data.
2. A utility to compute the maximum axis tick.

To find the maximum value in the array of (presumably objects) data you can do something similar to the following.

```
const findMaxVal = (arr, field) => Math.max(...arr.map((el) => el[field]));
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    customField: 23
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    customField: 31
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    customField: 29
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    customField: 7
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    customField: 13
  }
];

const findMaxVal = (arr, field) => Math.max(...arr.map((el) => el[field]));

console.log(findMaxVal(data, "customField")); // 31
```

[edit]

You mention in comments your data has this shape

```
[
  {xaxis: "bar-stacked", data:[0,12,19,50,2,30,14]},
  {yaxis: "bar-stacked", data:[2,4,15,29,10,3,1]},
]
```

To find the maximum value in the data you can simply spread `data` into `Math.max`.

```
const findMaxVal = data => Math.max(...data);
```

```js
const data = [
      {xaxis: "bar-stacked", data:[0,12,19,50,2,30,14]},
      {yaxis: "bar-stacked", data:[2,4,15,29,10,3,1]},
    ];

const findMaxVal = data => Math.max(...data);

console.log(findMaxVal(data[0].data)); // 50
console.log(findMaxVal(data[1].data)); // 29
```

[/edit]

To compute the max tick you can compute the next "chunked" tick after the maximum computed from data with something similar to:

```
const computeTicks = (val, chunk = 10) => Math.floor(val / chunk) * chunk + chunk;
```

or

```
const computeTicks = (val, chunk = 10) => Math.ceil(val / chunk) * chunk;
```

The difference between the two is what to "round" to if the value is even divided by the chunk amount, i.e. if data max 80 should have max tick of 80 or 90. This first would yield 90 while the second would yield 80.

```js
const computeTicks = (val, chunk = 10) => Math.floor(val / chunk) * chunk + chunk;

console.log(computeTicks(13)); // 20
console.log(computeTicks(19, 10)); // 20
console.log(computeTicks(20, 10)); // 30

console.log(computeTicks(13, 5)); // 15
console.log(computeTicks(13, 6)); // 18
console.log(computeTicks(18, 6)); // 24
console.log(computeTicks(19, 6)); // 24
```

Put these two together to compute the ticks to display in the graph.

```
const dataMax = findMaxVal(data, 'fieldIwantMaxOf'); // <-- compute max val before JSX return

...

<Bar
  ...
  options={{
    ...,
    scales: {
      ...,
      yAxes: [
        {
          ...,
          ticks: {
            ...,
            max: computeTicks(dataMax, 10) || 500, // <-- compute max or use default 500
          }
        },
        ...,
      ]
    }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: My Data is in this form: ```0:{xaxis: "bar-stacked", data:[0,12,19,50,2,30,14]}
1: {yaxis: "bar-stacked", data:[2,4,15,29,10,3,1]}```

Comment: @Sandhya are you asking how to compute the maximum y-axis data value from  `data[1].data`?

Comment: I have x-axis values as well as y-axis values, i want both the axis values  should be compared according to that highest value should be in y-axis. For an example: if x-axis values have [12, 14] and y-axis values have [1, 39] then overall y-axis range should be `53 (14+39)`

Comment: @Sandhya You made no mention of this in your post, but you can compute the maximum values for both x and y axis and sum them together. Since your data appears to be an array of numbers I'll update my answer to address.

Comment: I apologize for not posting accurately but issue is as mentioned in the comment description.

Comment: @DrewReese - your answer has helped me solve a problem that has bothered me foor weeks. I am so glad I came across your post. Thank you :)